# ArrayList values set to last value after exiting for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that is supposed to create a List of `Name` Objects from a dataset which contains a name and 11 ints representing the popularity of the name through the decades.

Example of data:

```
Zelda 436 420 468 526 789 961 938 0 0 0 0
Zulma 0 0 0 0 0 0 837 0 0 0 0
```

Currently the dataset is read in correctly and when I check the `Name` objects from within the for loop everything is correct.

But after the `for` loop exits, all values within the `ArrayList` have the same popularity values as the last entry, while `name` values remain correct.

What should happen:

```
Zelda 436 420 468 526 789 961 938 0 0 0 0
Zelda [436, 420, 468, 526, 789, 961, 938, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What actually happens:

```
Zelda 436 420 468 526 789 961 938 0 0 0 0
Zelda [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 837, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Data and output of last entry:

```
Zulma 0 0 0 0 0 0 837 0 0 0 0
Zulma [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 837, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Code:

```
public static ArrayList<Name> createNameArray(String[] data) {

    int nameLength;
    String name;
    String pops;
    ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>();
    int[] popsInts = new int[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // Checking data array, no missing data here
        System.out.println(data[i]); //returns correctly
        nameLength = data[i].indexOf(' ');

        name = data[i].substring(0, nameLength);
        pops = data[i].substring(nameLength + 1);

        for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
            popsInts[k] = Integer.parseInt(pops.split(" ")[k]);
        }

        names.add(new Name(name, popsInts));

        // Checking if Name object added to names is correct which it always is
        System.out.println(names.get(i)); //returns correctly


    }

    // If I print out values of the ArrayList here, everything is wrong
    return names;

}
```

How I am calling from the main method:

```
ArrayList<Name> list = createNameArray(data);
// Printing out ArrayList, all values are wrong except last one
// Using a regular for loop produces same results
for(Name n : list) { 
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

I have tried using a `Name[]` but the same thing happens.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix the error?

Comment: Create `int[] popsInts = new int[11];` **in the loop**. As is, you have one array that your add multiple times to your `List`.

Comment: What is the implementation of `Name`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that worked, but I don't understand why it worked. popInts was changed every loop to the new values and I was printing each name object after it was added to the ArrayList, which printed correct values. How does creating the int array outside the loop have an effect on what happens after the loop exits even though inside the loop it works perfectly? Thanks for the quick response by the way :) edit: Jack explained it in their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `Name` class is probably something defines as

```
class Name {
  String name;  
  int[] popsInt;

  Name(String name, int[] popsInt) {
    this.name = name;
    this.popsInt = popsInt)
  }
}
```

So you are storing a reference to an `int[]` inside `Name` instance. But the array you pass to the constructor is just one and it's constructed outside the loop that parses all the data:

```
int popsInt = new int[11];
for (each game) {
  popsInt = parse data
  list.add(new Name(name, popsInt));
}
```

So you construct a `Name` by passing a reference always to the same array, so in the end they all point to the same set of 11 values.

You must either copy the data passed or allocate a new array on each call, eg:

```
for (each game) {
  int[] popsInt = new int[11];
  popsInt = parse data;
  list.add(new Name(name, popsInt));
}
```

Now each `Name` instance gets its own array.

Comment: Yes, otherwise,  the constructor could make a copy of the array.

Comment: @MauricePerry: indeed I specified it in my answer _"You must either copy the data passed.."_

Comment: OK, sorry. That said, I think the constructor should always make a copy of whatever it wants to keep.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought that when you did something like `this.popsInt = popsInt;` it copied the array but I understand now that is not what happens.